# Change Permission to file with bash script

Tags: bash

I'm new with bash scripting. Why this bash script isn't working?

```
!/bin/bash

FILE_PATH=~/myFile.txt

function list()
{
    ls -l $FILE_PATH
}

function mod1()
{
    if [ ! -r $FILE_PATH ]; then
        chmod g+r $FILE_PATH
    else
        echo "File is already readable!"
    fi

}

function mod2()
{
    if [ -r $FILE_PATH ]; then
        chmod g-r $FILE_PATH
    else
        echo "File is not readable!"
    fi
}

function changePermissions()
{
    if [ "$1" = "g+r" ]; then
        mod1
    elif [ "$1" = "g-r" ]; then
        mod2
    fi
}

function result()
{
    list
    echo "Change Permission:"
    changePermissions
    list

}

result
```

I guess that error in if...else statement (function changePermissions). When I input g+r or g-r in console after ./nameScript.sh, permission not changing.

Comment: You can only alter permissions if you have superior permission. Generally, this means that you need to launch such a script as `root` (either your login as `root` and you launch the script, or you login "normally" and launch the script, using `sudo`).

Comment: To change the permissions, you need to be the owner of the file (or root); to change the owner, you need to be root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` changes the meaning for each function. To keep `$1` the same meaning you need to keep passing it down, i.e.

```
result()
{
    list
    echo "Change Permission:"
    changePermissions $1 # pass result argument as changePermissions argument
    list
}

result $1 # pass script argument into result argument
```

Also, the `function` keyword is not required, so, I removed it.